# Creating Terms and Conditions link

Tags: ios

"By clicking Register you are agreeing to our Terms and Conditions"

What is the easiest option to implement in the code where the entire above line is made clickable (this launches a modal view that shows the terms and conditions) AND the word "terms and conditions" is underlined in blue.

We tried various options.

1) We created a UIWebView and tried loading a html into it. But the html was rendered as is.
eg: "html body.../body html"

2) We tried to create a button with a label over it but we were not able to create a borderless button.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We were able to create the formatting by using a webView. We used one of the delegate of webView to complete the process. Here is sample code

```
NSString *html = @"<html><head><title>Terms and Conditions</title></head><body style=\"font-family:verdana;font-size:10px;\"><p>By clicking \"Register\" you are agreeing to our <a href=\"showlicenses://toc\"><b><u><font color=\"blue\">Terms and Conditions.</font></u></b></a></p></body></html>";  
   [termsWOutlet loadHTMLString:html baseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com/message"]];  


- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{

   NSLog(@"%s",__FUNCTION__);
   NSURL* u = [request URL];

   if( [[u scheme] isEqualToString:@"showlicenses"] ) {
      NSLog(@"in %s",__FUNCTION__);
      [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"loadTNC" sender:self];
      return NO; // DO NOT attempt to load URL
   }

   return YES; // if you want to allow the URL to load
}
```